Recieving [WinError 14001] when using Python request_html's .render
UPDATE: The issue is resolved after I reinstalled Python from a different source. I was previously using the Windows store Python and am now using the download from python.org
Same issue as this and this.
Receiving OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail when I run a Python program on VSCode executing the line.
r.html.render(sleep = 1)

I have tried the solutions offered in previous posts but the error persists. I can launch \local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\chrome.exe from the computer normally. I have also downloaded more versions of chromium and can use them as normal but experience the same error when using it from Python.
Using command-line sxstrace.exe, below is what I got.
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\chrome.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\chrome.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="&#x2a;",publicKeyToken="(I removed this)",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0"
    INFO: Reference: 117.0.5938.0,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="117.0.5938.0"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="&#x2a;",publicKeyToken="(I removed this)",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture AMD64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls\6.0.0.0_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Auto Servicing Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,processorArchitecture="AMD64",publicKeyToken="(I removed this)",type="win32",version="6.0.22621.3672".
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.22621.3672_none_2713b9d173822955.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.22621.3672_none_2713b9d173822955.manifest.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="AMD64",publicKeyToken="(I removed this)",type="win32",version="6.0.22621.3672".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture AMD64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.22621.3672_en-US_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui\6.0.22621.3672_en_6595b64144ccf1df\Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
INFO: Resolving reference 117.0.5938.0,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="117.0.5938.0".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture 117.0.5938.0,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="117.0.5938.0".
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\117.0.5938.0.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\117.0.5938.0.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\117.0.5938.0\117.0.5938.0.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win\117.0.5938.0\117.0.5938.0.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference 117.0.5938.0,language="&#x2a;",type="win32",version="117.0.5938.0".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.


Where did you get your Python from?

Hi, according to the prompt shows that the assembly cannot be found in WinSxS. And did not find manifest for culture en. You can try reinstalling requests_html library. And use the command pip install --upgrade python to update the python environment. Or by copying the Chrome installation information to its lookup directory C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\1181205\chrome-win. Try this and see if that solves the problem.

I'm using Visual Studio's Python interpreter located in a .venc folder. However, when I installed requests_html, I got a warning saying, " The script pyppeteer-install.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH."

If you try to change the path to here, then install the library again. See if that solves the problem.

I reinstalled Python from python.org then added it to path, which did end up working! Thank you

The issue is resolved after I reinstalled Python from a different source. I was previously using the Windows store Python and am now using the download from python.org
